# Using GRASS GIS 7.3 for Atmospheric Correction of Sentinel-Data

Tags: grass-gis, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction, grass-7.3

I read that GRASS GIS version 7.3 will be able to atmospheric correct Sentinel-2 Data. After downloading this version, which is still in development, I imported the Data and put all needed information in a text file. After launching the program i.atcorr with all necessary data, a warning message appears: "**WARNING: The sun is not raised**"

All information in the text file hopefully are as they needed. Has anyone alreade made experience with atmospheric correction of Sentinel-2 Date in GRASS GIS?

Comment: As is, it's unlikely that anyone here will be able to sufficiently answer this. You need to specify the data you are working with (or where you got it) and the actual steps you took to get the error. Even better would be isolating a set of data that can be used to reproduce the error and sharing that as well.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the new user [tour].  I have voted to close your question for two reasons: 1) because you have encountered a warning or error using Development software - this should be taken back to the developers to verify, and 2) you have not given any information about your data or the actual steps you followed, so potential answerers can't reproduce your process to test.

Comment: Please add the text file content to your question.

Comment: BTW: you can also open a bug report here: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/

Comment: @Oto. Even if the question is closed, I am interested if you solved the issue. Regards